# Why does Django pass a variable to a template like this?

Tags: python, django

I am adding a variable to a dictionary like this:

```
rr_context["start_date"] = c.start_date
```

And then I pass the dictionary to `render_to_response`:

```
return render_to_response(
        rr_template,
        rr_context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then in template I try to format it this way:

```
{{ start_date|date:"F" }}
```

But it returns nothing. I found the problem is for some reason Django passes a variable looking like this: `(datetime.date(2011, 10, 7),)`. I don't know why it happens this way.
I read the docs and I think I did it right way. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `start_date` is a tuple and not a single date value. That's why the `date` filter doesn't work.

You should check that `c.start_date` is a date, because it looks like it's a tuple.

Comment: Oh, man, that was such a dumb error I did. I entered **rr_context["start_date"] = c.start_date,**  instead of **rr_context["start_date"] = c.start_date**, so I just removed comma nad it worked fine!